# Count occurrences in string via MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count the occurrences of a string within the column "diagnosis".

What I am doing now is simply this - it gets my needed results

```
SELECT COUNT(*), diagnosis
FROM patients
WHERE diagnosis like "%OS1%"
UNION

SELECT COUNT(*), diagnosis
FROM patients
WHERE diagnosis like "%OS2%"

... and so on
```

Sometimes in my table the strings can occur twice (e.g. OS1, OS2), I want to count every single occurence of the strings.

I think it would be a pretty easy task in another language but I want to do it in pure SQL.

Comment: How to know which OS1, OS2 etc values to search for?

Comment: The strings are limited to OS1-OS6 and CH1-CH6

Comment: Put those values in a separate (temporary?) table and join with it!

Answer (score 2):

Put the OS1-OS6 and CH1-CH6 values in a diagn table. `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), d.diagnosis
FROM patients p
RIGHT JOIN diagn d
   on p.diagnosis like concat('%', d.diagnosis, '%')
group by d.diagnosis
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(OS1) as OS1_total, sum(OS2) as OS2_total, sum(OS3) as OS3_total,
sum(OS4) as OS4_total, sum(OS5) as OS5_total, sum(OS6) as OS6_total, 
sum(CH1) as CH1_total, sum(CH2) as CH2_total, sum(CH3) as CH3_total,
sum(CH4) as CH4_total, sum(CH5) as CH5_total, sum(CH6) as CH6_total
FROM
(
SELECT (case when diagnosis like '%OS1%' then 1 else 0 end) as OS1,
(case when diagnosis like '%OS2%' then 1 else 0 end) as OS2,
(case when diagnosis like '%OS3%' then 1 else 0 end) as OS3,
(case when diagnosis like '%OS4%' then 1 else 0 end) as OS4,
(case when diagnosis like '%OS5%' then 1 else 0 end) as OS5,
(case when diagnosis like '%OS6%' then 1 else 0 end) as OS6,
(case when diagnosis like '%CH1%' then 1 else 0 end) as CH1,
(case when diagnosis like '%CH2%' then 1 else 0 end) as CH2,
(case when diagnosis like '%CH3%' then 1 else 0 end) as CH3,
(case when diagnosis like '%CH4%' then 1 else 0 end) as CH4,
(case when diagnosis like '%CH5%' then 1 else 0 end) as CH5,
(case when diagnosis like '%CH6%' then 1 else 0 end) as CH6
FROM patients
) as mytable
```

Comment: That one fixed it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you find the answer useful, please mark it as useful by clicking the up arrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), diagnosis
FROM patients
GROUP BY diagnosis;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM patients 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(diagnosis, "(OS[1-6]|CH[1-6])")
```

You may also check out link below if you're interested. Not sure if it's what you're looking for though:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html